# SSAS error process : A request for a connection ... pool could not be granted

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc, ssas, ssas-tabular

I got this error when I try to process (Full) my cube :

***The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Failed to execute XMLA. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: A request for a connection from the data source pool could not be granted. Retrying the evaluation may solve the issue..
'..***

Do you have any idea ?

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the setting on your data sources.

If the maximum number of connections is too low, you might see this error.

When you do the process data, the data model initials several connections to your data sources. If the number of connections exceeds the allowed maximum number, error happens.

[Maximum Number of Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK0d2.png)